# In Excel, how do compare different worksheets that have a different number of rows by only the rows with the same names

Tags: excel

I have data in multiple different sheets in the same workbook.  These sheets have a protein name on the left most side and its corresponding data in the columns to the right, the sheets all have a different number of proteins.  I want to compare the data of proteins of the same name with those of the same name in the other sheets.
For example the protein calm1 is in row 13 in the first sheet which has 345 rows.  But in the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th sheet it is in row 14, 12, and 15 respectively.  The sheets also have different number of rows.  How would I compare a specific data value in one of the columns next to calm1 in sheet 1 with those in the others.  It is also possible that a sheet doesn't have the protein listed in it, in which case it should just ignore that sheet and carry on.
I will need to do something like this for all ~300 proteins in each sheet.  Is there a fast way to do this?

Comment: Did you try using [VLookup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.